# How to model strings and their motion for Newton's cradle in A-Frame

Tags: html, physics, aframe

I am trying to make a representation of Newton's Cradle in A-Frame. I'm not trying to model actual physics, just get something that looks close. My problem is creating something that represents the string holding the ball and getting it to animate in a similar way as the ball (to follow it).

I have tried a using a cylinder (right side) and found difficulty in keeping the top part of the cylinder in place with the rotations.

I have tried using a meshline from a community library and have found difficulty in being able to modify the second vertex of the path attribute to follow along with the ball.

Are there any suggestions for what type of object I should be using the attempt this and how to animate it for desired outcome? If you check the GH, I am also using aframe-curve-component to guide the position of the balls, and would love to make use of that somehow.

snippet...

```
        <!-- line for ball -->
        <a-entity meshline="lineWidth: 2; path: -4 1 -10, -4 8.5 -10; color: #999"
                rotation="0 0 0">       
        </a-entity>

        <!-- string for ball -->
        <a-cylinder height="8" radius="0.015" color="white" position="4 5 -10">
            <!--<a-animation property="position" to="7 2.25 -10" dur="1000" delay="4000"></a-animation>
            <a-animation property="rotation" to="0 0 30" dur="1000" delay="4000"></a-animation>-->
        </a-cylinder>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pivot the cylinder to move the animation origin to the top of the cylinder and not the middle of it.

Using animation component (https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/animation) that will ship with next version of A-Frame.

Something like...

```
<a-entity animation="property: rotation; from: 0; to: 45; dir: alternate; loop: true">
  <a-entity class="pivot" position="0 -<HALF OF CYLINDER HEIGHT> 0">
    <a-cylinder ...></a-cylinder>
  </a-entity>
</a-entity>
```